# How to trigger a css animation upon SignalR StateHasChanged event

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, css-animations

I have a page that shows wait times. On another server i have an exe that will send updated wait times to this page via SignalR. When an update is sent to this page it will update the data but i also want it to trigger a css animation for each row that is/has been updated.

I have it working the way i want with a hover event. How can I trigger the animation when StateHasChanged is invoked?

Comment: Maybe you can call js after call `StateHasChanged`.Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about how to call js in blazor.

Answer (score 0):

When you update a row, also set a CSS class on the row that adds the animation to the row.

`<div class="... animation1">...</div>`

Because you might update the same row more than once, you will need two class names that trigger the same animation - toggle between `animation1` and `animation2`

`<div class="... animation2">...</div>`

This also means you need to track the state of the rows CSS classes.